# Substitute a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, core-language

In the following code, I'm trying to substitute `Sin[x]` for `f[x]`. What's the right way to do it so that f'[x] gets replaced with `Cos[x]`?

```
e = f[x] + f'[x]
e /. f[x] -> Sin[x]
```

Comment: And `e/. f->(# Sin[#]&)` for `f=x Sin[x]`?

Comment: Wynne, that's right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e /. f -> Sin
```

> ```
> Cos[x] + Sin[x]
> ```